# How do I refresh the token in a cometd client talking to a Salesforce Platform EventBus?

Tags: salesforce, cometd

I'm using cometd to listen to platform events generated in Salesforce. My cometd client configuration code looks like

```
this.client.configure({
      url: `${this.org.instance_url}/cometd/46.0`,
      requestHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${salesforceToken}`
      },
      appendMessageTypeToURL: false
    });
```

where the `salesforceToken` is obtained using the refresh token. This all works fine for a while but if there are no events for a considerable period of time (anecdotally anywhere between 6-24 hours), then my client seems to *expire* and no events are received. If I refresh the token and restart my listener, things start working again.

Is there a way to keep the listener active other than writing some sort of timer to restart the process every few hours after inactivity ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to refresh the token again

Whenever there is no activity on the channel, the server closes the connection after a specific time.

In that time client receives a **403 (Unknown client)** status code, and the client has to handshake again withing 110 seconds.

By default, CometD tries to reconnect without any user interaction and If the client doesn't reconnect within the expected time, the server removes the client's CometD session.

Once the connection gets reconnect, all the channel subscriptions will be removed by ComedD, and we have to subscribe to the channel again in order to receive events.

In order to do so, we have to make use of **meta/Handshake** callback to resubscribe to the channel again.

Answer (score 0):

see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_client_connection.htm, paragraph "After Invalid Authentication"

"Streaming API regularly validates the OAuth token or session ID while the client is connected. If client authentication is not valid, the client is notified with the 401::Authentication invalid error and an advice field containing reconnect=none. After receiving the error notification in the channel listener, the client must reauthenticate and reconnect to receive new events."